# Layers Dockable in Gimp Install not available via Window pull-down menu

Tags: 14.04, gimp

Ubuntu 14.04 installed and "working" on my Asus N53S (8gb ram)
Installed Gimp both via Installer and bash console.
Some of the dockables are not available via the 
window menu.
eg Layers can only be accessed via Add Tab - Layers on a visible dockable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the docks do not appear in the main window by default. You have to go to Windows option (in the topbar) when GIMP is opened and in focus. Then hover on Dockable Dialogs. Select the dialog you want to appear, and it will.